# Best way to improve this pyspark join

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, pyspark

I need to merge 250 csv files but this way is really slow, any other method?

```py
df1 = spark.read.csv("/Users/mac/Desktop/A.csv", header=True, sep=",", inferSchema = True)
df2 = spark.read.csv("/Users/mac/Desktop/B.csv", header=True, sep=",", inferSchema = True)
df3 = spark.read.csv("/Users/mac/Desktop/C.csv", header=True, sep=",", inferSchema = True)
df4 = spark.read.csv("/Users/mac/Desktop/D.csv", header=True, sep=",", inferSchema = True)
df5 = spark.read.csv("/Users/mac/Desktop/E.csv", header=True, sep=",", inferSchema = True)
df6 = spark.read.csv("/Users/mac/Desktop/F.csv", header=True, sep=",", inferSchema = True)
df7 = spark.read.csv("/Users/mac/Desktop/G.csv", header=True, sep=",", inferSchema = True)


dfs = [df1,df2,df3,df4, df5,df6,df7]
df = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)
```

I tried:

```py
dfs = []
for i in os.listdir('/Users/mac/Desktop/'):
    if i != ".DS_Store":
        dfs.append(f"spark.read.csv({i}, header=True, sep=',', inferSchema=True")
```

this code returns as a string:

```
["spark.read.csv(A.csv, header=True, sep=',', inferSchema=True",
 "spark.read.csv(B.csv, header=True, sep=',', inferSchema=True",
 "spark.read.csv(C.csv, header=True, sep=',', inferSchema=True",
 "spark.read.csv(D.csv, header=True, sep=',', inferSchema=True",
```

i was seeking this output:

```py
[DataFrame[identifier: string, identifier_type: string, timestamp: string, time_zone_name: string, device_lat: double, device_lon: double, country_short: string, province_short: string, ip_address: string, device_horizontal_accuracy: double, source_id: string, record_id: string],
 DataFrame[3660506e-fbe6-4575-8e04-7ac9e09006c3: string, gaid: string, 2020-01-29 05:56:29 UTC: string, America/Matamoros: string, 25.531531: double, -103.39389: double, MX: string, MX.07: string, _c8: string, 4382: double, _c10: string, 93733528-93d4-4774-8676-529b8af32646: string],
```

Answer (score 2):

We can read all the **`csv`** files at one time from the directory.

Try with

```
df=spark.read.csv("/Users/mac/Desktop/*.csv", header=True, sep=",", inferSchema = True)
```

Comment: my approach was `df = reduce(lambda x,y: x.unionAll(y), 
            [spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv')
                       .load(f, header="true", inferSchema="true") 
             for f in dfs])`
I am running this now, it takes a while, next I will test your code. Thanks